# How to auto Layout Labels

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout

I want to layout my labels like this using auto layout. It works fine in iPad 10.5. But when I move to any other versions of iPad with a larger screen, this design brokes. Anyone, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Use stackView for this.

Comment: When I use stack view it works fine on Ipads but not in iPhones. @vivekDas

Comment: Is the screen shot the expected layout or the broken one ? (assume its broken one ?) If you want them to be equi distant from one another, you can add equal width constraint for label 2-5 to label 1.

Comment: The screenshot attached here is actually the iPad screenshot. It works fine on the iPad. But when I moved to iPhone the controls are overlapped each other. I need the same layout on both iPad and iPhones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 4**

Use stack view

**Step 1**. insert `labels` inside of `stack view`
like that

[image]

**Step 2.** add `constraints` on stack view
from `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` alignment **according to your requirement**
like that ->

[image]

**Step 3.**
**Use `Stackview` properties**

a.) set `axis` of **Stack view**  `Horizontally` as well as  `vertically`.

b.) set alignment according to requirements.

c.) set Distribution according to requirements (here i used fill equally).

b.) set Spacing between `labels` .

See here ->

[image]

Now run. it will work, it will show same in all Device like `iPhone` and `iPad` and also (horizontal and vertical).

**it will show like this(iPhone6splus)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the time. But when I move to iPhone the labels are overlapped each other

Comment: Please check stack view Properties once and also  constraints. because  label will not be overlapped in stack view,  never ever.

Comment: I have one more doubt can we use the same stack view on UITableViewCel?
I have a customized cell similar to this and it also has the same problem.

Comment: welcome @SIDHARTHPU  yes we can use it in TableView Cell as well as Every other place where you got same problem.

Comment: You save my day @Ravindra Bhati. Now everything works fine. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can add constraints by "Add missing Constraints". 
1.select your labels 
2.And click the "Add missing Constraints"

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you create/checked constrations only for iPad or iPhone. Change a type of device scoping on Storyboard editor and you can find errors. Take care about UI for all of device types.